# Count nonempty cells in column, if row contains word

Tags: excel, excel-formula, google-sheets

This is what I have now:

```
=COUNTA(FILTER(A14:O,SEARCH($A$4,A14:A),SEARCH("*",F14:F)))/2
```

Looks something like this

```
     A   B C D E F [...]
14 word1 a h     X
15 word2     c k X
16 word3          
17
18 word1     c   
19 word2 a     j X
20 word3   b     X
[...]
```

What I want it to do:
Basically I want to know how many cells in column F aren't empty but only count those where the row contains word1 in column A

What it does:
If column F is empty it returns 0.5, when it's supposed to be 0
If column F has X in row 18 but not 14 it returns 1, as it's supposed to
If column F has X in row 14 but not 18 it returns 6, when it's supposed to be 1
If column F has X in both row 14 and 18 it returns 7, when it's supposed to be 2
If column F has X in any row but 14 it returns the amount of Xs, as it's supposed to

I feel like I'm making this sound more complicated than it actually is.

Comment: Like `=COUNTIFS(A14:A20,"word1",F14:F20,"<>")`???

Comment: Yep, that does exactly what I need. Thanks.

Comment: You are welcome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=COUNTIFS(A1:A7,"word1",F1:F7, "*")
```

SYNTAX : [`COUNTIFS`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIFS-function-dda3dc6e-f74e-4aee-88bc-aa8c2a866842)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the list of words is in Column A and Column F contains whatever, you could use:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A1:A7="word1")*(F1:F7>0))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are picking up a lot of extra counts from columns B:E (some of which seem to be zero-length strings and look like empty cells, but still register).

Try

```
=COUNTA(FILTER({A14:A,F14:F},SEARCH($A$4,A14:A),SEARCH("*",F14:F)))/2
```